# How to initialize iOS Charts to show data points at a specific x-axis range, e.g. last 6 months from today?

Tags: swift5, ios-charts

I have a question about iOS Charts by Daniel Cohen Gindi here. The figure below shows my full dataset drawn out as a scatter chart. With the x-axis labels going from January to December (let's say 2018), and then again January to December (2019).

[image]

The problem is that I don't want to show all data in range, but just in the past six-month range, July-December, as I want the scatter chart view to look like depicted below. (Note: assume the right-most data point is today.)

[image]

I want the user to be able to scroll *right* to see more data points in the past. I've tried this Swift code below but it would "lock" the x-axis to show July-December, and the user can't scroll *right* to see past data:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scatterChartView: ScatterChartView!

scatterChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 17.5 // + or - 0.5 for padding
scatterChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(months.count) - 0.5
```

And then I would try this code below but it would initially show data from the first 6 months, January-June of 2018. However, the user could scroll *left* to see the later months.

```
scatterChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
```

Close but not quite. Is there any way I could show data from the last 6 months upon loading the scatter chart, and have the user scroll *right* to see past data?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

```
scatterChartView.moveViewToX(17.5)
```

Per documentation, moveViewToX(float xValue) – Moves the left side (edge) of the current viewport to the specified x-value. The view port refers to "what is visible on the chart, aim of the view).

Upon chart loading, the viewport is initialized showing the most recent 6 months, and I can scroll right to see past data.